# c# SSIS - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

[image]I am working on an SSIS package (This is something new to me). I am using a Script component as Source, I am using a ReadOnlyVariable (VarPackagePath) and assigned it a value 'C:\Development\SSISProjects\VS2012\GetErrorColumn\GetErrorColumn\Package.dtsx' which is the location of the project.
The script I used was to get the relavent column where the error occured.
Link I was following : http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-error-column-name-in.html

I have debugged my c# code and I am getting an error at this line :

```
TaskName = ExecutableNode.SelectSingleNode("DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='ObjectName']", NameSpcMgr).InnerText;
```

Error is : `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'`.

My C# code :

```
 public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    /*
      Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
      For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
    */
    //Declare Variables
    String TaskName;
    String ColName;
    Int32 ColLineageID;
    String ColKey;

    //Read the Package File
    XmlDocument PackageFile = new XmlDocument();
    PackageFile.Load(Variables.VarPackagePath);

    //Create Hash Table 
    Hashtable ColKeyTable = new Hashtable();


    XmlNamespaceManager NameSpcMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(PackageFile.NameTable);
    NameSpcMgr.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts");

    foreach (XmlNode childnode in PackageFile.SelectNodes("//*[@lineageId != '' and @name != '']"))
    {


        XmlNode ExecutableNode = childnode.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::DTS:Executable[1]", NameSpcMgr);
        TaskName = ExecutableNode.SelectSingleNode("DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='ObjectName']", NameSpcMgr).InnerText;
        ColName = childnode.Attributes["name"].Value;
        ColLineageID = Convert.ToInt32(childnode.Attributes["lineageId"].Value);
        ColKey = TaskName + ColName + ColLineageID;
        if (!ColKeyTable.ContainsKey(ColKey))
        {
            ColKeyTable.Add(ColKey, DBNull.Value);

            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.ColLineageID = ColLineageID;
            Output0Buffer.ColName = ColName;
            Output0Buffer.TaskName = TaskName;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/suggestion please.

Comment: My guess would be that the previous line 'XmlNode ExecutableNode = childnode.SelectSingleNode` it didn't find the node in the XML

Comment: Hi CABBott, thank you for your prompt response. I have followed that link as it was. Where is it looking for the node? I have no clue why and how it is using it.

Comment: I would suggest debugging and looking at what the value of `childnode` is first. This is what's being searched for the `SelectSingleNode` that's not finding the node.  Also, it is possible to test `ExecutableNode` for null if it doesn't find the node.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the child node to the question itself. One thing I fail to understand was, when I created the script component, I have not mentioned the cvs input file to it, so how is it going to create lineageId's for the columns.  Does the attached screenshot make any sense

Comment: `SelectSingleNode` simply searches the given XML node based on the XPath it's given, in this case `ancestor::DTS:Executable[1]`. Here's a reference to XPath examples to understand what it's trying to find: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for that, but I did not understand what it is not finding. Any suggestion how to fix this.